# How to get the difference between two Timestamp in Postgres SQL in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ((extract (epoch from (end_time::timestamp - start_time::timestamp))))::integer from Trip_Details where td_id = "+transacId+" ");
```

I am trying this query to get the diff between two timestamps i.e.,start_time, stop_time.

but getting below exception

```
ERROR: stderr - org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:timestamp, :integer] [SELECT ((extract (epoch from (end_time::timestamp - start_time::timestamp))))::integer from Trip_Details where td_id = 1 ]
```

Its working fine on PG Admin console of postgres and getting output as 202 sec in integer format.

Please help me to trace out the error and resolve it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you `Query query = session.createSQLQuery('SELECT ((extract (epoch from (end_time::timestamp - start_time::timestamp))))::integer from Trip_Details where td_id = '+transacId+' ');` in Java?..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect double quotes treated you bad. A colon before word in Java is used to set variable. I assume if you change your code to:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT cast((extract (epoch from (cast(end_time as timestamp)- cast(start_time as timestamp)))) AS integer ) from Trip_Details where td_id = "+transacId+" ");
```

It should start working...